# USB host, STM32. f_mount returns FR_DISK_ERR

Tags: stm32, usb-host

I'm trying to connect a USB flash drive to an STM32F407VGT6.

IDE Keil,
I used compilers 6.19 and 5.06.

```c
FRESULT fresult;
case HOST_USER_CLASS_ACTIVE: //The HOST_USER_CLASS_ACTIVE event occurs
Appli_state = APPLICATION_READY;
fresult = f_mount(&USBHFatFS, "0:", 1); //The HOST_USER_CLASS_ACTIVE event occurs
```

`f_mount` returns `FR_DISK_ERR`.

---

I'm using CubeMX to generate code.
STM32F407VGT6 is configured as a host.
I used this instruction to configure CubeMX https://controllerstech.com/stm32-usb-host-msc/
The code I use is different:
I simply add this to the `usb_host.c` file:

```c
#include "fatfs.h"
FRESULT fresult;
FATFS MyUSBH;
```

and this

```c
fresult = f_mount(&USBHFatFS, "0:", 1);
```

"0:" is the correct path to the flash drive, this is the same as empty brackets "".
I also used other paths: "", "1:", "2:", "3:"

```c
/* USER CODE END Header */

/* Includes ------------------------------------------------------------------*/
#include "usb_host.h"
#include "usbh_core.h"
#include "usbh_msc.h"
/* USER CODE BEGIN Includes */
#include "fatfs.h"
/* USER CODE END Includes */

/* USER CODE BEGIN PV */
/* Private variables ---------------------------------------------------------*/
FRESULT fresult;
FATFS MyUSBH;
/* USER CODE END PV */

/* USER CODE BEGIN PFP */
/* Private function prototypes -----------------------------------------------*/

/* USER CODE END PFP */

/* USB Host core handle declaration */
USBH_HandleTypeDef hUsbHostFS;
ApplicationTypeDef Appli_state = APPLICATION_IDLE;

/*
 * -- Insert your variables declaration here --
 */
/* USER CODE BEGIN 0 */
BYTE work[_MAX_SS];

/* USER CODE END 0 */

/*
 * user callback declaration
 */
static void USBH_UserProcess(USBH_HandleTypeDef *phost, uint8_t id);

/*
 * -- Insert your external function declaration here --
 */
/* USER CODE BEGIN 1 */

/* USER CODE END 1 */

/**
  * Init USB host library, add supported class and start the library
  * @retval None
  */
void MX_USB_HOST_Init(void)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN USB_HOST_Init_PreTreatment */

  /* USER CODE END USB_HOST_Init_PreTreatment */

  /* Init host Library, add supported class and start the library. */
  if (USBH_Init(&hUsbHostFS, USBH_UserProcess, HOST_FS) != USBH_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  if (USBH_RegisterClass(&hUsbHostFS, USBH_MSC_CLASS) != USBH_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  if (USBH_Start(&hUsbHostFS) != USBH_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  /* USER CODE BEGIN USB_HOST_Init_PostTreatment */

  /* USER CODE END USB_HOST_Init_PostTreatment */
}

/*
 * Background task
 */
void MX_USB_HOST_Process(void)
{
  /* USB Host Background task */
  USBH_Process(&hUsbHostFS);
}
/*
 * user callback definition
 */
static void USBH_UserProcess  (USBH_HandleTypeDef *phost, uint8_t id)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN CALL_BACK_1 */
        switch(id)
        {
        case HOST_USER_SELECT_CONFIGURATION:
        break;

        case HOST_USER_DISCONNECTION:
        Appli_state = APPLICATION_DISCONNECT;
        break;


        case HOST_USER_CLASS_ACTIVE:     //The HOST_USER_CLASS_ACTIVE event occurs
        Appli_state = APPLICATION_READY; //................---------------------
        fresult = f_mount(&USBHFatFS, "0:", 1); //The HOST_USER_CLASS_ACTIVE event occurs
        break;


        case HOST_USER_CONNECTION:
        Appli_state = APPLICATION_START;
        break;

  default:
  break;
  }
  /* USER CODE END CALL_BACK_1 */
}
```

Power is supplied to the flash drive, for this I use this code in the main function:

```c
HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOC, GPIO_PIN_0, GPIO_PIN_RESET);
```

The `HOST_USER_CLASS_ACTIVE` event occurs, which means the connection of the flash drive is recognized.

I've used several flash drives.

The adapter Mini USB - USB to flash drive is short.

I also tried formatting:

```c
f_mkfs("", FM_FAT32, 0, work, _MAX_SS);
```

`f_mkfs` also returns `FR_DISK_ERR`.

I formatted the flash drive on my computer for different formats: FAT, FAT32, exFAT.

Comment: Is there a question? Have you tried to debug why it returns an error or what the error is? What hardware you are using? Can you show the schematic?

Comment: I'm trying to understand why f_mount returns FR_DISK_ERR.
I have already found the reason, I wrote the answer below.
But I don’t understand why this situation is happening.
I need to write delays in a while loop.

The diagram is definitely not needed here, the problem is in the code.
I'm working with STM32VGT6

Answer (score 0):

I found the reason for the problem:

If I write `HAL_Delay(1000);` in `main.c` in `while` loop
then `f_mount` returns `FR_DISK_ERR`.

Doesn't matter until MX_USB_HOST_Process(); I write HAL_Delay or after MX_USB_HOST_Process();

**Can this be fixed somehow?**

[image]

Comment: You are sort of asking a new question in your answer. And fix what? Don't call the delay as it does nothing useful and prevents handling of USB so it doesn't work.

Comment: Why can't I call HAL_Delay in a while loop?
The STM32VGT6 is designed for more than just USB.
So in the while loop I want to do a lot of other things using HAL_Delay.

Comment: This is a response to my first post, but with a question inside. Yes. But in essence these are exactly parts of the same topic.

Comment: You still need to handle USB in time when there is something to handle. You can't expect 1 second delays are allowable when handling USB. The HAL documentation should state the requirements for calling USB handling code. The basic example just handles USB in a loop. If you want to do something useful that takes long, maybe try switching to run multiple code tasks under an RTOS.